# Udemy: If a student is enrolled, does this mean he has already paid the course?

Tags: udemy

I have a question about the Udemy platform for video online courses.
I see that this course has been enrolled by more than 26.000 students and its cost is 200 dollars: https://www.udemy.com/devslopes-ios10/

Does this mean that all this students have paid the course, which means 5 million dollars?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that all this students have paid the course, which
>   means 5 million dollars?

Yes it means all the student paid for the course, but it doesn't mean 5 million dollar Udemy & the instructors runs a lot of discount time to time. The same course might be available as $10 some time. Mostly when a new course comes it would be lot less then $200 dollars.